# Tried to put data on the API but it didn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to upload to the API but failed.
There was no error message but the data was not uploaded.
Here is my code:

```
List<String> parts = email.split('@');
    String username = parts[0];
    Account u = Account(
        userId: email,
        name: username,
        email: email,
        imgUser:
            'https://as1.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/03/46/83/96/1000_F_346839683_6nAPzbhpSkIpb8pmAwufkC7c5eD7wYws.jpg',
        connect: false,
        phoneNumber: '',
        rate: 0,
        password: password);

    Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
      "${u.email}": Account.fromJson(u.toJson())
    };

    String urlString =
        'https://education-a9946-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Account.json';
    final url = Uri.parse(urlString);
    await http.put(
      url,
      body: json.encode(userData),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    );
```

account.g.dart file

```
part of 'account.dart';

Account _$AccountFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Account(
      userId: json['userId'] as String?,
      name: json['name'] as String?,
      email: json['email'] as String?,
      imgUser: json['imgUser'] as String?,
      phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'] as String?,
      rate: json['rate'] as int?,
      connect: json['connect'] as bool?,
      password: json['password'] as String?,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$AccountToJson(Account instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'userId': instance.userId,
      'name': instance.name,
      'email': instance.email,
      'imgUser': instance.imgUser,
      'phoneNumber': instance.phoneNumber,
      'rate': instance.rate,
      'connect': instance.connect,
      'password': instance.password
    };
```

I don't want to use Firebase's built-in methods because I want to practice using the normal API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: http.put method only send that data witht he request method PUT. so it will not change the json file in the server